# Android: getting datas with two ValueEventListener from firebase database (setting adapter before Arraylist Expires)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an app and in database there are users like doctor and patient. There may be doctors userId in patient datas and patient `userId` in doctor datas. Because in app doctor will see some information about his/her patient. I develop this chunk of codes, but I could not add patient informations to Arraylists before setting adapter. Here is my codes:

```
  myRef.child("users")
            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("patients").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    AddingPatients addingpatient = ds.getValue(AddingPatients.class);

                    if(addingpatient.getConfirm().equals("yes")){

                        myref.child("users").child(addingpatient.getUserId()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    Users patient = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                                    name.add(patient.getName()+" "+patient.getSurname());

                                    sicks.add(patient.getSicks());
                                    patientuid.add(patient.getUserId());
                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            PatientSelectionAdapter adapter= new PatientSelectionAdapter(getContext(),name,sicks,hastauid);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

When I debug codes I saw that, patient information is adding to lists after setting adapter. So my `RecyclerView` is empty. How can i fix that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please move the following lines of code:

```
PatientSelectionAdapter adapter= new PatientSelectionAdapter(getContext(),name,sicks,hastauid);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

Inside the second `onDataChange()` method like this:

```
myref.child("users").child(addingpatient.getUserId()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Users patient = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);

            name.add(patient.getName()+" "+patient.getSurname());

            sicks.add(patient.getSicks());
            patientuid.add(patient.getUserId());
        }
        PatientSelectionAdapter adapter= new PatientSelectionAdapter(getContext(),name,sicks,hastauid);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {}
});
```

This is happening because `onDataChange()` has an asynchronous behavior. Please see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** mode details.

Comment: I've tried it but it's a problem: the patient is taking photos of the wound and updating the total number of photos after each photo. When this is the way the new photo is added, 4 data of the same patient is displayed in the recycler view.

Comment: How to fix that problem Alex?

Comment: Let's stick to one question at a time. Using my above code, is your `RecyclerView` still empty?

Comment: No, code is working. There are patients in RecyclerView.

Comment: Can we pass second question or post a new topic?

Comment: In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Move the following line to top outer onDataChange().

   ```
   PatientSelectionAdapter adapter= new PatientSelectionAdapter(getContext(),name,sicks,hastauid);
   ```
2. Insert following line before returning from inner onDataChange()

   ```
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   ```